# Javascript integrating underscore and groupBy

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, momentjs

I'm new to all things `Javascript` so I am undertaking a little bit of `node.js`.

I'm currently using some third party `APIs` and manipulating the data.

I stumbled upon `underscore` to help me tackle this as the data being returned contained multiple `objects`.

I used the `zip` function to pair the values of two separate `arrays`, shown below.

```
[ '2016-06-28 18:48', '455102464' ],
[ '2016-06-28 18:53', '234782720' ],
[ '2016-06-28 18:58', '338894848' ],
[ '2016-06-28 19:03', '301309952' ]
```

While looking into `zip` I also noticed a function called `groupBy`. My aim was to reduce the amount of records and group the values against 1 day, as opposed to having multiple records of the same day.

I have tried to implement the following but not to avail.

```
var groups = _.groupBy(valueArr, function() {
    return moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
});
```

Any feedback would be much appreciative to outline what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is an array of arrays (produced by the zip), then the groupBy iteratee should expect an array parameter.

```
var arrayOfArrays = [ [ '2016-06-28 18:48', '455102464' ],
                      [ '2016-06-28 18:53', '234782720' ], // etc
_.groupBy(arrayOfArrays, function(array) {
    var dateString = array[0];
    // extract the day from date and return that day
    var date = moment(dateString, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    return date.format('D');
});
```

This will produce:

```
{ 6: [ [ '2016-06-28 18:48', '455102464' ], [ '2016-06-28 18:53', '234782720' ] ],
  N: [ pairs with first element date on the Nth day of the month ], etc
```

You might actually want to groupBy day of year, as opposed to day of month, but you should be on your way once you have a regular date object available.